# MedusJs admin giving 401 status on every request

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean, medusajs

I recently deployed my medusaJs project on digital ocean. the deployment was successful and the backend endpoints are return the necessary JSON information when I hit them with a status of 200. How ever when I try to use my admin panel all my requests in my network tab have a status of 401 and the response is unauthorized. Has anyone encountered the same issue and is their a fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case you either have problem with CORS on your backend so try change it to this according to medusajs [docs](https://docs.medusajs.com/development/backend/configurations#admin_cors-and-store_cors) :

```
ADMIN_CORS=/http:\/\/*/
```

and add `MEDUSA_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL` which specify the backend url that the requests are send to  :

```
MEDUSA_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL=http://example.domain.com
```

medusajs [docs](https://docs.medusajs.com/admin/configuration#dev-command-options)

> You can add the following options to the medusa-admin dev command:

- `--backend` or `-b`: a string specifying the URL of the Medusa
  backend. By default, it's the value of the environment variable
  `MEDUSA_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL`. For example, medusa-admin `dev --backend example.com` .
- `--port or -p`: the port to run the admin on. By default, it's 7001.
  For example, `medusa-admin dev --port 8000`.